# Node version in npm EBADENGINE error is different from node -v

Tags: node.js, linux, unix, npm, ubuntu-22.04

Whenever I run `sudo npm i` in my project folder to install dependencies, it prints out lots of errors like this:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'peek-readable@5.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.16' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

The error says that I *have* node v12.22.9 and npm v8.5.1, but after I run `node -v` and `npm -v` it returns v18.10.0 and v8.19.2 respectively.

I am on Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: What if you run `sudo node -v`? Possible new node is only in your path and not the root users path

Comment: Curious if you found a solution. I have the exact same issue right now.